# Will this PCI express 3.0 video card work with my current motherboard and power supply?

Tags: memory, graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply, pci-express

Before I purchase a new video card (current one died after a few years) I was trying to figure out if I could use a PCI express 3.0 with the motherboard and power supply (listed below) would work with it. I'd like to just build a whole new computer but my funds are short at the moment. I know they are backwards compatible. But does the motherboard have enough power for the connection. I just didn't see that with the specs. Does anyone have an idea on this before I make the purchase? Thank you in advanced. OR if you might have a better suggestion as far as a replacement video card? I play games but I don't have to have the graphics turned all the way up, not picky.

ASUS Sabertooth X58 LGA 1366 Intel X58 SATA 6Gb/s USB 3.0 ATX Intel Motherboard
-- newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813131665

CORSAIR Enthusiast Series CMPSU-850TX 850W ATX12V v2.2 / EPS12V v2.91 SLI Certified CrossFire Ready 80 PLUS Certified Active PFC Power Supply
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817139009

MSI GeForce GTX 960 GTX 960 GAMING 4G 4GB 128-Bit GDDR5 PCI Express 3.0 x16 HDCP Ready SLI Support ATX Video Card
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814127860

Comment: How about instead of a negative vote, we see an answer or request for more information?

Comment: PSU specs say Power consumption: 120W
Recommended Power Supply: 400, so it should be fine. [As far as using a 2.0 card in a 3.0 slot](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2438733/pci-backwards-compatible-pci.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably look at one of these sites which will allow you to best estimate the draw of your system running at idle and full load. As a general rule, the power draw of your system should not exceed 70% of the output of your power supply.

One example is below.

http://outervision.com/power-supply-calculator